# Monitoring what files are changed

Tags: linux, files, inotify

Is there a way in linux (possibly using Inotify?) to "log" what files are edited, live?

Answer (score 2):

You can setup `auditd` to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Open Source Tripwire](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tripwire/) or the [commercial Tripwire](http://www.tripwire.com) products.

Answer (score 0):

[LINK](https://serverfault.com/questions/48587/is-there-a-linux-log-for-when-a-user-is-denied-access-to-files-due-to-permissions/48619#48619)  has a good writeup on how to do it with auditd